# Cant able to access Clicked elements value

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, javascript

I want to show an alert message which should have the Value of element on which we are clicking , For that I have written some code as,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function filterProducts() {
        var clicked = this;
        alert($(clicked).val());
        return {
            Reference: $(this).val()
        };
    }


</script>


@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("ReferenceValue") //The name of the dropdownlist is mandatory. It specifies the "id" attribute of the widget.
    .DataTextField("ValidValue") //Specifies which property of the Product to be used by the dropdownlist as a text.
    .DataValueField("ReferenceValidValueID") //Specifies which property of the Product to be used by the dropdownlist as a value.
    .BindTo(Model)
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("GetReferenceValidValue", "GetData").Data("filterProducts"); //Set the Action and Controller name
                })
                .ServerFiltering(true); //If true the DataSource will not filter the data on the client.
            })
    .SelectedIndex(0) //Select first item.
)
```

But while clicking on the Dropdown, It doesn't show alert mesage written in function "filterProduct".

On that time it gives some kind of Exception Like,

```
Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterProducts() {
        var clicked = this;// this property not acccess  like this 
        alert($(clicked).val());
        return {
            Reference: $(this).val()
        };
    }
```

you can try like

```
$("selector").click(function(){
 ^^^^here you can write $("button") and etc as your requirement
            var clicked = this;
            alert($(clicked).val());
            return {
                Reference: $(this).val()
            };

}):
```

Comment: I am using Kendo Grid as you can see above, In that we load data on clicking on Dropdown list.